# Need help Solving Taylor-Maccoll Equation

Tags: differential-equations, physics

```
Clear[m1, θs, θc, θ1, m1n, m2n, m2, vi, vri, vti, s1]
Print["γ[x]="];
γ[x] = Input["Specific Heat Ratio", Number]
Print["m1="];
m1 = Input["initial Mach number", Number]
Print["θs="];
θs = Input["cone shock angle in degrees", Number]
θc = Input["cone angle in degrees", Number]
Print["θ1="];
θ1 = N[ArcTan[(2*N[Cot[θs*Degree]]*(((m1^2*(N[Sin[θs*Degree]])^2) - 
     1)/(m1^2 (γ[x] + N[Cos[2*θs*Degree]]) + 2)))]/Degree]
m1n = m1*N[Sin[θs*Degree]]
m2n = Sqrt[(m1n^2 + (2/(γ[x] - 1)))/(((2*γ[x]/(γ[x] - 1))*m1n^2) - 1)]
m2 = m2n/(N[Sin[θs*Degree - θ1*Degree]])
vi = ((2/((γ[x] - 1)*m2^2)) + 1)^(-1/2)
vri = (N[Cos[(θs*Degree) - (θ1*Degree)]])*vi
vti = -(N[Sin[(θs*Degree) - (θ1*Degree)]])*vi
s1 = NDSolve[{(((γ[x] - 1)/2)*(1 - vr[θ]^2 - (vr'[θ])^2)*(2*vr[θ] + (vr'[θ]*
    N[Cot[θ*Degree]]) + (vr''[θ]))) - (vr'[θ]*(vr[θ]*vr'[θ] + vr'[θ]*vr''[θ])) == 0, 
    vr[θ1] == vri, vr'[θ1] == vti}, vr, {θ, 0, 30}]
```

Above is the code I am using to try and solve the Taylor-Maccoll equation.  However, I am not sure how to overcome the stiff system error.  Any help is much appreciated.
The inputs are gamma=1.4, m1=2.0, thetas=40, thetac=10

Comment: I have reformatted your code and, in the process, corrected a typo in `m2n`.  However, readers cannot run your code without knowing the values of a number of constants.  Please provide them as an edit to your question.

Comment: What does `θ1` represent?

Comment: That is the flow angle that is created immediately after the shock wave.  In the link below, this angle is denoted by delta. http://documents.mx/documents/cone-notes.html

Comment: $\theta{}1$ appears to represent the guessed shock angle.  [This](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/coneflow.html) might be helpful.

Comment: My guess is that the range of integration should be `{θ, θ1, θs}`, not `{θ, 0, 30}`.  Certainly, the region of integration must lie outside the cone.

Comment: I have not completed the code since I cannot get the integration to work, but at any rate, the integration continues until vr'[theta]>0.  When this derivative is positive it means the flow would be inside the cone, so the integration stops and the result would be the actual cone angle.  The cone angle input in the program is not yet used.  Also, the integration needs to just decrease incrementally from the flow angle down until the above condition is met.

Comment: But, it cannot start inside the cone.

Comment: The integration is used to find the actual cone angle, so whether that is 2 degrees or 50 it should not make any difference in the integration.  Since cone angles are rarely less than 10 degrees, that could be used as the minimum value.  Is there a way to just incrementally decrease theta from theta1 rather than giving the range?

Comment: The cone is a solid object, is it not?  In any case, `NDSolve` does integrate incrementally, stopping when it cannot go further.

Comment: yes, physically, but the equation is such that it allows the integration to "be inside the cone", this is where vr'[theta] would go from a negative to a positive value and the code needs to stop.  If there is a way to have the integration step away from theta1 in a decreasing fashion, that would be preferable.  I only added the integration limits because I could not find a way to do this.

Comment: I have run your code.  It steps away in both directions, stops at `θ == 10.6106` with a singularity, and at 23.2, where it goes negative.  I emphasize that the equation is not stiff.

Comment: how did you get the 23.2 value? That is very close to what the cone angle should be.

Comment: `WhenEvent[vr[θ] < 0, "StopIntegration"]`.  But, I emphasize that the solution of your equation does not go to zero at any point for `θ < θ1`.  Would you like me to provide all this as an answer?

Comment: I think that may be what I am looking for as far as the whenevent, but it should be stop integration when vr ' [theta] > 0.

Comment: Not possible.  You give it boundary conditions at θ1 of  `vr[θ1] == vri`, which is positive, and `NDSolve` must integrate from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This computation can be carried out using

```
s1 = NDSolve[{(((γ[x] - 1)/2)*(1 - vr[θ]^2 - (vr'[θ])^2)*(2*vr[θ] + (vr'[θ]*
    N[Cot[θ*Degree]]) + (vr''[θ]))) - (vr'[θ]*(vr[θ]*vr'[θ] + vr'[θ] v''[θ])) == 0, 
    vr[θ1] == vri, vr'[θ1] == vti, WhenEvent[vr[θ] < 0, "StopIntegration"]}, 
    vr, {θ, θc, θs}]
```

Note that the ODE is singular where

```
Denominator[Simplify@Solve[(((γ[x] - 1)/2)*(1 - vr[θ]^2 - (vr'[θ])^2)*(2*
    vr[θ] + (vr'[θ]*N[Cot[θ*Degree]]) + (vr''[θ]))) - (vr'[θ]*(vr[θ]*vr'[θ] 
    + vr'[θ]*vr''[θ])) == 0, vr''[θ]][[1, 1, 2]]] // Chop // Rationalize
(* -1 + vr[θ]^2 + 6 Derivative[1][vr][θ]^2 *)
```

vanishes.  It is, however, not stiff anywhere.  The solution, then, is

```
Flatten[vr["Domain"] /. s1]
(* {10.6106, 23.1842} *)
Plot[vr[θ] /. s1, Evaluate[Join[{θ}, %]], AxesLabel -> {vr, θ}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesOrigin -> {θc, 0}]
```

[image]

The goal of this computation is to determine where `vr[θ]` vanishes, which here is at `23.1842`.

Comment: My pleasure.  Good night.